# Why does unit group of valuation ring contains $K^{\times}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $K_v$ be a completion of $K$ by non-archimedean valuation $v$ of $K$ and $U_v$ be a unit group of valuation ring $R_v$.

Then why $K^{\times}\subset U_v$?(for almost all $v$)

This implies principal idele is idele.

**Edit** this is wrong

Comment: This is obviously false (take any nonzero element of $K$ of positive valuation).  Maybe you have misstated something?

Comment: Check your language, please. What's happening is that for every element $z\in K^*$ we have $z\in U_v$ for all but finitely many $v$. But the set of valuations $v$ for which this holds depends heavily on $z$. And $K^*\subseteq U_v$ is false for all non-trivial valuations.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think so too. But how about the definition of idele class group https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2015fa/LectureNotes25.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiFld3wlfrjAhXPGaYKHaK0Co4QFjAIegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw3jH3UdUryQC_dN4kuibkd3

Comment: Did you understand my comment? The inclusion of $K^*$ in the ideles is determined at the level of individual elements of $K^*$. Each and every one of them being a unit w.r.t. all but finitely many valuations. And that is exactly what your source says also. It does not follow that $K^*$ would be contained in any of the groups of units. When $K=\Bbb{Q}$, the element $2\in K^*$ is a $p$-adic unit for all choices of $p$ other than $2$. Similarly $6/5$ is a $p$-adic unit as long as $p\notin\{2,3,5\}$. The same for all the non-zero rationals.

Comment: (cont'd) Yet $1/p\in K^*$ is not a $p$-adic unit, so $K^*$ is not contained in $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ for any prime $p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah, I understand now, thank you. But why is this also holds about general $K,v$? I think that argument seems not to be depending only on the axioms of valuation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen (perhaps based on this argument and $K_v$ is local field, using extension of valuation theorem...)

Comment: Do you understand how it works now ?

Comment: @reuns What do you mean? I understood the case $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K = \Bbb{Q}$ then $$\Bbb{A_Q} = \{ a_\infty\prod_p a_p \in \Bbb{R} \times \prod_p \Bbb{Q}_p, \text{ for all but finitely many } p, a_p \in \Bbb{Z}_p\}$$

it is a commutative unital ring whose $1$ is $1_\infty \prod_p 1_p$ (with $1_p$ the $1$ of $\Bbb{Q}_p$) and

$$\Bbb{A_Q}^\times = \{ a \in \Bbb{A_Q}, \exists b \in \Bbb{A_Q}, ab = 1\}$$
$$=\{ a_\infty\prod_p a_p \in \Bbb{R}^\times \times \prod_p \Bbb{Q}_p^\times, \text{ for all but finitely many } p, a_p \in \Bbb{Z}_p^\times\}$$

For $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ let $x_p$ its image in $\Bbb{Q}_p$ then the diagional embedding $x \mapsto x_\infty \prod_p x_p$ is a ring homomorphism $\Bbb{Q \to A_Q}$ and it sends $\Bbb{Q^\times \to A_Q^\times}$.

With $x = \frac{n}{m}$ we have $x \in \Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ whenever $p \nmid nm$.

The other thing to know is that $\prod_p \Bbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim \Bbb{Z} /(n)$ is the set of limits of sequences of integers that converge $\bmod n$ for every $n$.